# An error occurred while installing pg (0.21.0), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, bundle, shopify

I am trying to follow [this tutorial about Shopify Apps](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/blob/master/docs/Quickstart.md).
First I try:

> bundle install

**But it gives me this error**

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /tmp/bundler20171024-12759-18v2l7apg-0.21.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/ext
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171024-12759-2yizk4.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for
building a client-side application.
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for
building a client-side application.
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.3
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /tmp/bundler20171024-12759-18v2l7apg-0.21.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/pg-0.21.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/bundler20171024-12759-18v2l7apg-0.21.0/gems/pg-0.21.0 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/tmp/bundler20171024-12759-18v2l7apg-0.21.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/pg-0.21.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (0.21.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.21.0'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  pg
```

But if I try:

> gem install pg -v '0.21.0'

**It also gives me error:**

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/ext
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171024-12993-1t8i3d6.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.3
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/pg-0.21.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.21.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/pg-0.21.0/gem_make.out
```

I have read that

> sudo apt-get install libpq-dev

**Should work, but, yes... error:**

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. (This is the gemfile:)**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'shopify_app', '~> 7.0.0'
```

What should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the reason of your problem is here

```
libpq-dev : Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

You should solve it to install `libssl-dev`, it is not related to ruby/pg, but it is required for them to install pg gem properly.

Comment: "but it is required for them to install pg gem properly" why?

Comment: Okay but now I am getting libpq-dev: command not found

Answer (score 15):

Actually this worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev ruby-dev
```

It required me to install two packages `libpq-dev` and `ruby-dev`

Comment: `brew install libpq` did it for me on mac

Answer (score 10):

I think you don't have postgresql installed. Try:

```
brew install postgresql
```

Comment: When your answer is too short, it's better to send as a comment.

Answer (score 5):

Try installing postgres:

> brew install postgresql

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this running the "rails new" command on my Mac (Rails 5, High-Sierra) with the `--database=postgresql` option turned on. This is kind of a restating of things mentioned in earlier answers, but I think it might be helpful.  The issue is because I've installed Postgres as an app in my Applications folder and when the "rails new" command runs it can't find the includes it needs to install the pg gem.  All I had to do is let the system know where they are.  So I executed this in the Terminal:

```
export CONFIGURE_ARGS=“with-pg-include=Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/include/“
```

Then I could run with out issue:

```
rails new MyAppName --database=postgresql
```

Comment: Of all the questions and tips I've found, yours seems most pertinent to my situation. I get the error "can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header" with one particular rails app, but not another rails app. Question is: Do I have to use Postgrsql if I have mysql already installed?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you forgot to install ruby-dev packages.
It solved probled for me.

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```